# Can't change __block variable from inside SLRequest block

Tags: objective-c, xcode, scope, objective-c-blocks, block

I'm trying to change the value of an int inside a block. (In this code example, the SLRequest itself is only context-setting from my full app and is not expected to work here -- just compile and run ok so I can test setting the int. Socialframework needs to be included in the project for this example to compile. Output is included below.)

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // This SLRequest stuff is just to provide the context for the block in question below
    NSString * theURLstr = @"http://someurl";
    NSURL * theNSURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:theURLstr];
    SLRequest *theRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:theNSURL parameters:nil];
    [theRequest setAccount:nil]; // 

    // This is our test value.  We expect to be able to change it inside the following block
    __block int test = 44;
    NSLog(@"(BEFORE block) test is: %d", test);

    [theRequest performRequestWithHandler:
     ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error2)
     {
         // We get here late.
         test = 27;
         NSLog(@"(INSIDE block) test is: %d", test);

     }];
    // We get here fine, but test isn't changed
    NSLog(@"(AFTER block) test is: %d", test); 
}
```

// ---
OUTPUT:

```
2013-02-10 19:13:53.283 debugExp1[92743:c07] (BEFORE block) test is: 44
2013-02-10 19:13:53.285 debugExp1[92743:c07] (AFTER block) test is: 44
2013-02-10 19:13:53.312 debugExp1[92743:1303] (INSIDE block) test is: 27
```

Notice the out-of-sequence output lines.  It starts and finishes before it executes the middle. How can I fix this?  I just want to change the int value in that location and have it stick for use outside the block.

=== UPDATE ===

I'm finding multiple tangential versions of this question online, but in unusable forms to my purpose.  So maybe I'm posing my question in a way that is unanswerable.  Let me try adding some context.

My app is assembling data from multiple Twitter API calls of different types as specified by Twitter.  I'm not building tables for display.  I just want the data in ivars and eventually managed objects.  The app has a lot to do other than just get the Twitter data, so I don't want to put too much of the structure of my app inside a single performRequestWithHandler block just so I can access its returned data at some point. To me, getting the data from the net is a utility operation, not the sole app design determinant.  Some of my API calls depend specifically on data gathered from other types of API calls executed earlier in a specific order.

I need to know when those previous calls have finished so I can use the ivar values I set from their data objects.

That is, I need a way to make API call#1, assign assorted return data to ivars, do other stuff with the ivars outside the performRequestWithHandler block, make API call#2 and #3, etc., based on what call#1 and subsequent API calls returned, and eventually shuffle off to other viewControllers to display the processed data from the multiple API calls' return values in various ways.

I totally get that performRequestWithHandler is executed on an unspecified thread which will get executed I-don't-know-when. I'm not worried about UI long waits due to synced network access latency because I intend to specify very short wait times.  I'm not going to make my users sit around waiting for a slow network connection!  If the connection is slow, I'll show an activity indicator briefly and give up waiting quickly to show an alert.  That part of the app isn't my challenge of focus here.

My challenge is assembling the returned data from multiple performRequestWithHandler calls in one place *after* some or all of them have finished.

It looks to me like performRequestWithHandler may be too high level a call to achieve the kind of sync control and data access I need. I don't know.

The code example above was just the simplest way I could think of to isolate and demonstrate my problem in a simple way that compiles. I've tried many variants but no joy so far.

Hope this helps clarify the design idea I'm working with.

Thanks for any specific help, clues or ideas you may be able to offer. A minuscule working code sample would be a Godsend at this point, but I'll keep working on it and post a solution if/when I find one.

Comment: BTW, you can't *not* worry about long waits on the main thread in a mobile app. (1)The OS will kill your app if you freeze the main thread for too long waiting on a synchronous connection. (2) You can't show a wait indicator if the main thread is stuck. (3) you don't control what network your users are on typically, or how many times they switch networks while using your app.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've answered your own question in that, as you can see, you are reading the __block variable (twice) before the block has even executed.

This is an asynchronous method that you are calling. It will complete sometime after `viewDidLoad` has returned. So the log output is not out of sequence at all. What you are seeing is the reality of how these calls with play out.

You should think about your design and realize that this request may take a long time to complete, especially if the user is on a slow network, etc. So you'll need to decide what you present to the user while the request is in flight, and then how you will update the user when the request does finally complete.

**EDIT**

From your comments, let me try to give you a small example to hopefully get you unstuck. I can't necessarily write for you a complete working example here that takes into account all of the possible concurrency, memory mgmt, and design implications. But, one *simple* way to get started is to schedule a block that just updates some property on your view controller (assuming your view controller is around long enough for the request to either complete or fail!)

```
[theRequest performRequestWithHandler:
 ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error2)
 {
     int test = 27;
     NSLog(@"(INSIDE block) test is: %d", test);

     // now schedule a block on the main queue which will update our UI with this
     // new data "27"
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         // here we are on the main queue, ready to read our test and do something with it.
         NSLog(@"(updating the UI) test is: %d", test);

         // now that we know we can read the data, we can save that data, update the UI, do
         // whatever is appropriate for your app
         // maybe this is as simple as:
         self.someProperty = test;

         // yes, there is a possible retain cycle here. Worry about that after
         // you have the basic mechanics of this understood.

     });

 }];
```

I hope that points you in the right direction. Beyond this, I would suggest there are lots of good courses out there (free and paid) that can help you understand these fundamental concepts that are really pretty important for mobile development (on Android **or** iOS). Dealing with asynchronous methods and events is a fact of life for anything beyond "hello world" on a mobile device.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I see your new edit to your question. That really helps explain the context here. If you have a lot of different async calls happening, then you probably want to get this out of your view controller and into some data controller that does all of this work and assembles your results. In that case, the same basic principles apply, you'll just have more calls and more sequencing to think about.

Comment: How can I tell when SLRequest has completed?

Comment: Your block will execute when the request is complete. So in that block you can do whatever it is you need to do when the request is complete. (just keep in mind that block may not necessarily be run on the main thread).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I guess I'm missing something. Still can't make it work. Does anyone have a working code example of what I want to do? I just want to change that int value inside the SLRequest block and access it later. Sorry if my question is amazingly stupid.

Comment: Where is the variable you are trying to change now? I assume you have changed your design some since you posted this question. Maybe update your question with your current code.

Comment: I'm thrashing here. Been through a couple dozen experiments, searched the web high and low, searched my books. Nothing works, including this variation based on the idea that viewDidLoad is on the main thread, so I'm trying to set values on the main thread from inside the block.  But obviously it's not working.  Here's what I've got now:

Comment: Drat, the comment box won't give me enough chars to post my code.

Comment: May I suggest that the best way to teach me how to do this is to show me some example, any example that works, including the design you mention, Firoze?  I really don't know what you mean.

Comment: RE your update, Firoze, THANK YOU!  Yup, that does print the correct value on the main thread, but the code-context for printing it is still in the block. I need to access the changed value from outside the block, later.  I need a way to know, from outside the block,  when that block has finished executing.  Guess I'll have to hit the books.  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Han, see my latest edit where I set a property from the block. That property will then be available outside of the block. as for knowing when to read it, you can call a method from the block, you can post a notification from the block, you can use KVO, there are lots of options there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24344/discussion-between-han-and-firoze-lafeer)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution I came up with based on Firoze's suggestion re NSNotification. I'm using a string instead of an int, in this version, but it's the same difference for my test purposes. NSNotification is actually better than I had hoped!  Its ability to transport an object from one thread to another will be of great help, tho I only use nil here.  Output is below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Test SLRequest wireframe
NSString * theURLstr = @"http://someurl";
NSURL * theNSURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:theURLstr];
SLRequest *theRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:theNSURL parameters:nil];
[theRequest setAccount:nil];

// Set default
self.myNewTestStr = @"default";
NSLog(@"In viewDidLoad, self.myNewTestStr DEFAULT is %@", self.myNewTestStr);

// Listen on "weGotOurValue"
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gotOurValue) name:@"weGotOurValue" object:nil];
// [ActivityAlert presentWithText:@"Please wait"];

// Pretend to get some data from the net
[theRequest performRequestWithHandler:
 ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error2)
 {
     // Not sure I need this dispatch, btw
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         // Change the ivar
         self.myNewTestStr = @"changed";

         // Post notification "weGotOurValue" 
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"weGotOurValue" object:nil];
         // [ActivityAlert dismiss];
     });
 }];
}

// Called by NSNotificationCenter when it receives
// a postNotificationName:@"weGotOurValue" message
- (void) gotOurValue {
    NSLog(@"In gotOurValue, self.myNewTestStr is %@", self.myNewTestStr);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
2013-02-12 17:44:52.300 debugExp1[5549:c07] In viewDidLoad, self.myNewTestStr DEFAULT is default
2013-02-12 17:44:52.354 debugExp1[5549:c07] In gotOurValue, self.myNewTestStr is changed
```

Answer (score -1):

-(void)reloadProfile
{

```
// 1

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest
                      requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                      requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                      URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"]
                      parameters:@{ @"fields" : @"id,first_name,last_name,gender,birthday,email,picture"}];

// 2
request.account = [FacebookController sharedFacebookController].facebookAccount;
// 3
__block NSDictionary *jsonDictD;
[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                     NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        // 4
        [AppHelper showAlertViewWithTag:123 title:APP_NAME message:@"There was an error reading your Facebook account." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        // 5
        NSString *decodedString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
        // NSLog(@"%@",decodedString);
        jsonDictD = [decodedString JSONValue];
        NSLog(@"%@",jsonDictD);
        if (jsonDictD)
        {
            [AppHelper saveToUserDefaults:[jsonDictD objectForKey:@"email"] withKey:@"email"];
            [AppHelper saveToUserDefaults:[jsonDictD objectForKey:@"id"] withKey:@"facebook_id"];


            [userImage setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[jsonDictD objectForKey:@"picture"] objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"url"]]]
                             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultPic.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
             {

                 userImage.image=image;
                 dummyImg=image;
                 [dummyImg retain];

             }
            failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
             {

             }];

            self.firstNameTextField.text=[jsonDictD objectForKey:@"first_name"];
            self.lastNameTextField.text=[jsonDictD objectForKey:@"last_name"];
            self.emailTextField.text=[jsonDictD objectForKey:@"email"];

            self.dobTextField.text=[jsonDictD objectForKey:@"birthday"];

            if ([[jsonDictD objectForKey:@"gender"] isEqualToString:@"male"])
            {
                gender=@"Male";
            }
            else
            {
                gender=@"Female";
            }
            //  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Get FB" object:nil];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                [[DubitAppDelegate getAppDelegate] hideActivityViewer];


            });
        }
    }
}];
```

}